# Nexus: maven repository parallel connection limitation?

Tags: maven, nexus

Our project intensively uses Maven3 for build, and a private Nexus (version 2.2) repository is used to host the snapshot builds and proxy artifacts from outside. It works fine.

Recently I am trying to speed up our maven build with parallel (-T parameter), and some random build failures are observed from time to time. The failures are mainly caused by failed dependency resolution, which is rarely happened in none parallel mode.

My question: is it possibly caused by parallel connection limitation in Nexus? Or any other possibility?

Thanks.

The build contains 20+ modules which usually takes 10 minutes to finish.
Here is the failure I got yesterday evening:

```
00:11:11 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project app-common: Could not     resolve dependencies for project com.abc.sbo.occ:app-common:jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [com.abc.sbo.occ:common-test:jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT (test), com.abc.sbo.occ:bo-frw-common:jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.9 (compile), org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.9 (compile), net.sf.jxls:jxls-core:jar:1.0.2 (compile), com.aspose.cells:aspose-cells:jar:8.2.1 (compile), junit:junit:jar:4.11 (test), org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.5 (test), nl.jqno.equalsverifier:equalsverifier:jar:1.1.3 (test), org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java:sonar-jacoco-listeners:jar:1.2 (test)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6: Could not find artifact org.apache:apache:pom:7 -> [Help 1]
00:11:11 [ERROR] 
00:11:11 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
00:11:11 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
00:11:11 [ERROR] 
00:11:11 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
00:11:11 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
00:11:11 [ERROR] 
00:11:11 [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
00:11:11 [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :app-common
```

Update: I toggled the -X option and caught below stack trace after one day's run. The declared missing artifact org.apache:apache:pom:7 does exist in Nexus for a long time. Maybe it indicates I have to upgrade Nexus to latest version?

```
14:00:47 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project app-common: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.abc.sbo.occ:app-common:jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [com.abc.sbo.occ:common-test:jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT (test), com.abc.sbo.occ:bo-frw-common:jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.9 (compile), org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.9 (compile), net.sf.jxls:jxls-core:jar:1.0.2 (compile), com.aspose.cells:aspose-cells:jar:8.2.1 (compile), junit:junit:jar:4.11 (test), org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.5 (test), nl.jqno.equalsverifier:equalsverifier:jar:1.1.3 (test), org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java:sonar-jacoco-listeners:jar:1.2 (test)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6: Could not find artifact org.apache:apache:pom:7 -> [Help 1]
14:00:47 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project app-common: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.abc.sbo.occ:app-common:jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [com.abc.sbo.occ:common-test:jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT (test), com.abc.sbo.occ:bo-frw-common:jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.9 (compile), org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.9 (compile), net.sf.jxls:jxls-core:jar:1.0.2 (compile), com.aspose.cells:aspose-cells:jar:8.2.1 (compile), junit:junit:jar:4.11 (test), org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.5 (test), nl.jqno.equalsverifier:equalsverifier:jar:1.1.3 (test), org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java:sonar-jacoco-listeners:jar:1.2 (test)]
14:00:47    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:210)
14:00:47    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:117)
14:00:47    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:258)
14:00:47    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:201)
14:00:47    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
14:00:47    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
14:00:47    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
14:00:47    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleThreadedBuilder$1.call(LifecycleThreadedBuilder.java:167)
14:00:47    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleThreadedBuilder$1.call(LifecycleThreadedBuilder.java:163)
14:00:47    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
14:00:47    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
14:00:47    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
14:00:47    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
14:00:47    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
14:00:47    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
14:00:47    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
14:00:47    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
14:00:47 Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.abc.sbo.occ:app-common:jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [com.abc.sbo.occ:common-test:jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT (test), com.abc.sbo.occ:bo-frw-common:jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.9 (compile), org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.9 (compile), net.sf.jxls:jxls-core:jar:1.0.2 (compile), com.aspose.cells:aspose-cells:jar:8.2.1 (compile), junit:junit:jar:4.11 (test), org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.5 (test), nl.jqno.equalsverifier:equalsverifier:jar:1.1.3 (test), org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java:sonar-jacoco-listeners:jar:1.2 (test)]
14:00:47    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:158)
14:00:47    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:185)
14:00:47    ... 16 more
14:00:47 Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to collect dependencies for [com.abc.sbo.occ:common-test:jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT (test), com.abc.sbo.occ:bo-frw-common:jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.9 (compile), org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.9 (compile), net.sf.jxls:jxls-core:jar:1.0.2 (compile), com.aspose.cells:aspose-cells:jar:8.2.1 (compile), junit:junit:jar:4.11 (test), org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.5 (test), nl.jqno.equalsverifier:equalsverifier:jar:1.1.3 (test), org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java:sonar-jacoco-listeners:jar:1.2 (test)]
14:00:47    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:258)
14:00:47    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:308)
14:00:47    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:150)
14:00:47    ... 17 more
14:00:47 Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6
14:00:47    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:331)
14:00:47    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:186)
14:00:47    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:412)
14:00:47    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:544)
14:00:47    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:240)
14:00:47    ... 19 more
14:00:47 Caused by: org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not find artifact org.apache:apache:pom:7
14:00:47    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:126)
14:00:47    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:813)
14:00:47    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:664)
14:00:47    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:310)
14:00:47    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:232)
14:00:47    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:322)
14:00:47    ... 23 more
14:00:47 Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact org.apache:apache:pom:7
14:00:47    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:538)
14:00:47    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
14:00:47    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:193)
14:00:47    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:122)
14:00:47    ... 28 more
14:00:47 Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact org.apache:apache:pom:7
14:00:47    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:528)
14:00:47    ... 31 more
14:00:47 [ERROR] 
14:00:47 [ERROR] 
14:00:47 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
14:00:47 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
14:00:47 [ERROR] 
14:00:47 [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
14:00:47 [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :app-common
```

Comment: Without more information (like exact error messages), anything is possible. It would also be interesting to know: Does that happen for your own artifacts for ones which are downloaded from other repositories? Releases or snapshots?

Comment: Most important thing is that you use at least Maven 3.1.1 or newer and furthermore use realy up-to-date Maven plugins cause there had been bugs in several plugins in particular in relationship with concurrent execution. And of course show the informations which has Aaron has mentioned. I'm using parallel build options for a long time. Large build (280 modules) Please show the error message you have got? BTW: How many modules do you have? How long does the build take?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I attached more for your information.

Comment: What's the error when you run with `-X`? If you can include only the part of the error, running with `-X` ...

Comment: First 20 module and taking 10 minutes is slow. How many tests are running?. Furthermore the error message gives me a hint that you might have network issues. Access to Maven Central or your repository manager (firewall / proxy?) you should check the whole build if there are warnings. Start with a clean build (remove local repository) and redirect logging into a file and afterwards check the log file.

Comment: The 20 modules contain 300k+ js and java code. 5 minutes needed for parallel build, and almost 10 minutes needed for sequential build. Since the reported missing artifact "org.apache:apache:pom:7" does exist in my Nexus repository, I guess it is mostly probably a bug in Nexus...